# Is it really better to respect the normal forms and create an additional table for one simple field?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-normalization

We organize runs, and we want to save **run results** and the **number of kilometers** that runners did run in their career. We have one table with every runners data (name, age, gender, etc. including an Id).

I see two ways of keeping the other data:

- Having **two more tables**. First one with the run length and the run Id, and the second one with 3 columns: runner Id, run Id and the runner's position. If I am right this would **respect the second normal form**, with no duplication.
- Having **only one table** which has the Runner Id, the run length and the runner position. The run length would there be **duplicated** for every runner (let's say about 20 each time).

Having two tables will bring additional benefits, like retrieving the order of a specific run or store additional data in the runs table, but we will only need to retrieve the positions of a runner and its total traveled distance. In this case, having only one table looks **way more optimized** than having two tables, since the duplication is for one field (an integer) and avoids storing a whole table and referencing its Id anyway.

We have only two integers to store, one for the run length and one for the runner's position. Thus, there's no heavy duplicate data.

Would the result be lighter by breaking the second normal form?

Comment: I've typically seen cases like these handled with data warehousing or "fact tables", especially for historical data that's never going to change again. The proof is in profiling, though. Debating on optimization without data is like trying to settle a footrace from a bar stool.

Comment: "Duplication" & "optimized" don't mean anything in particular so it's not clear what you're arguing. (And duplication isn't good or bad per se.) A NF applies to only 1 table, not across tables, so it's also not clear what you mean when you talk about violating 2NF. So again it's not clear what you are saying. Your 2nd design talks about "the run" length & position but either you forgot a run id column or it's not clear what you want to record. PS Total length is redundant given run lengths in that it is a function of them.

Comment: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. Yes or no questions are seldom useful & (since they ask for a yes or a no) are seldom asking for what the asker actually wants answered.

Comment: [Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)
What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question? How/why you are 1st stuck following what published/justified design method? What is your concrete demonstration of any problem querying & updating with either design?

Comment: Please use words & DDL for some 1 design to explain exactly what data you want to record. It's not clear from this & no design among your prose + 2 bullets can answer what the others do & your prose says unclear & contradictory things. Eg "only need to retrieve the positions of a runner and its total traveled distance"--What is the "only" trying to say? If you don't need run ids, why are you storing them? Etc. There is no point in discussing rearranging designs until you know what you want to remember. Normalization to higher NFs does not introduce ids. Etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, three tables data model it is (Oracle syntax, but disregard that; principle is just the same elsewhere):

```
SQL> create table runner
  2    (runner_id number primary key,
  3     name      varchar2(20)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> create table run
  2    (run_id    number primary key,
  3     name      varchar2(20),
  4     length    number
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> create table rxr
  2    (runner_id number references runner,
  3     run_id    number references run,
  4     position  number,
  5     constraint uk_rxr unique (runner_id, run_id)
  6    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

If it were only `runner` and *only one (additional) table*, that would be

```
SQL> create table oot
  2    (runner_id number references runner,
  3     length    number,
  4     position  number
  5    );

Table created.
```

which is an option, but worse than the previous one. You can calculate length - that's true - but you have no idea *where* (on which runs) that took place, so any additional statistics info would be impossible to collect. For example, which *track* is my favourite track? (right now, there was Wengen man slalom (alpine race) which would add length and position to my data, but - without actually knowing the venue - I can't compare runners between tracks ("I'm the second best runner in Wengen").

---

On the other hand, are you SURE that `run` (the 2nd table in the 1st piece of code) data won't change through time? For example, in Formula 1 car races: Imola has its ID and track length is well known. But then, they decide to make two corners out of one and length is changed, so even the 1st model I posted would be wrong (kind of). How about moving such data into the 3rd table?

```
SQL> drop table rxr;

Table dropped.

SQL> drop table run;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table run
  2    (run_id    number primary key,
  3     name      varchar2(20)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> create table rxr
  2    (runner_id number references runner,
  3     run_id    number references run,
  4     run_date  date,
  5     length    number,
  6     position  number,
  7     constraint uk_rxr unique (runner_id, run_id)
  8    );

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

Basically, *think twice*! Create data model which will suite your needs in long turn, don't take shortcuts as they might be counter-productive at the end.